# What does it mean L1 loss is not differentiable?

Tags: regression, loss-functions, differential-equations

I was looking through this lecture
https://davidrosenberg.github.io/ml2015/docs/3a.loss-functions.pdf

> Slide 3: Absolute or Laplace or L1 loss not differentiable

What does it mean `L1 loss not differentiable`? I understand that derivative not exist at x=0, but what practical problems can arise from this fact?

What does it mean `gives median regression`?

**Update:**

Looks like answer to the second question:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/363369/16843

**Update 2:**

Here is related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518869/how-does-tensorflow-handle-the-differentials-for-l1-regularization
It doesn't describe how tensorflow implement it, but example shows that at x = 0.0 the gradient = 0.0

Comment: Your last question is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251600.  The somewhat delicate analyses in the answers there, which avoid differentiating the loss, show one reason why lack of differentiability may be an issue.

Answer (score 6):

$L_1$ loss uses the absolute value of the difference between the predicted and the actual value to measure the *loss* (or the *error*) made by the model. The absolute value (or the *modulus* function), i.e. $f(x) = |x|$ *is not differentiable* is the way of saying that its derivative is not defined for its whole domain. For modulus function the derivative at $x=0$ is undefined, i.e. we have:

$$
\frac{d|x|}{dx} = \begin{cases}
-1, & x < 0 \\
1, & x > 0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Explicitly, the derivative is undefined at $x=0$.

Comment: I understand that derivative not exist at x=0, but what practical problems can arise from this fact?

Comment: Apart from making the theory based on differentiable loss functions inapplicable,  getting the wrong answers, or having your calculations fail, you mean?

Comment: Having Fact 1: L1 loss used in practice in regression, Fact 2: L1 loss not differentiable at x=0 what conclusions can we make? Option 1: L1 loss not differentiable at x=0 is not a problem Option 2: In practice people somehow overcome this problem while minimizing L1 loss, i.e. adding epsilon to x, when x is 0?

Comment: @mrgloom, researchers back-door this problem by adding a small value to x when it is zero, I have seen such solutions working in practice.

Comment: Alternatively you can sample uniformly from the sub-derivative at 0 (the closed interval [-1, 1]). There are many functions that are not differentiable at certain points for which this approach of sub-gradient sampling helps.

Answer (score 5):

**I understand that derivative not exist at x=0, but what practical problems can arise from this fact?**

$$ L = |x*a - y|; $$

$$  \frac{\partial L}{\partial a} = \dfrac{x\left(xa-y\right)}{\left|xa-y\right|} $$

When faced with loss equals zero for any sample you train your model with, the gradient calculator will need to divide expression by zero, which will cause error.

This is usually mitigated by, for example, adding a small value to denominator when $L$ is zero.

Comment: Derivation https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83861/finding-the-derivative-of-x-using-the-limit-definition

Answer (score 4):

+1 to both Tomasz and Alexey posts.

I would add that a good surrogate for the $L_1$ loss is the [Pseudo-Huber loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss#Pseudo-Huber_loss_function) function: $ L_{\delta }(x) =$ $\delta ^{2}\left({\sqrt {1+(x/\delta )^{2}}}-1\right)$ with $\delta = 1$. It allows us to approximate the $L_1$ rather faithfully away from $x=1$ and within $[-1,1]$ behaves like a quadratic. It has first (and second) derivatives everywhere.

[image]